# The number of featured questions

Tags: discussion, bounty

I wonder why the number of featured questions increased nowadays. It was around $30$ before and nowadays above $50$.

Comment: More users $\Rightarrow$ more questions $\Rightarrow$ more features questions, perhaps?

Comment: [What about restricting the number of featured questions?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10879/19341)

Comment: @user1729 in some months the number of user in mse was not doubled i guess..

Comment: @draks... thanks i had a look at it. It says that mse is expanding, in my opinion expending more in a way that the questions are increasing much more than answers

Comment: Asking more questions but getting fewer answers? Welcome to academia!

Comment: @user1729 I try to answer more questions than I ask but it happens that i rarely get answers nowadays although i was getting more answers before.

Answer (score 5):

The increase in the number of featured questions is roughly proportional to the increase in the total number of questions asked. The number of [Questions Asked by Day](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/8692/questions-asked-by-day) indeed doubled in recent months:

[image: Number of questions]

The chart shows overall growth influenced by season: the number of questions is lower during Northern Hemisphere summers and winter holidays.

> in some months the number of user in mse was not doubled i guess..

Since many (most?) questions are asked by relatively new users, it is more appropriate to compare the number of **new** questions to the number of **new** users. Which follows roughly the same trend, with very strong spikes during days when math.se was referred to on some more popular website. [New users per day](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/80302/new-users-per-day):

[image: new users per day]